# Using an IN or OR with spring data on a string column

Tags: spring, pagination, spring-data

We are using spring data and need to run a query where if a state is chosen we run it against the state and 'ALL' `WHERE state IN ('NY','ALL')` or `WHERE (state = 'NY' OR state = 'ALL)`

In the database `stateCode` is defined as a String, that allows up to 3 characters, state abbreviation or `ALL`

Our Entity is as follows

```
Documents.java
@Entity(name = "documents")
@Data
public class Documents {
    @Id
    private Integer docId;
    private String stateCode;
    private String displayName;
    private Integer isEmployee;
    private Integer categoryId;
    private Integer subjectId;
}
```

In our `DocumentService` we are using `ExampleMatcher` to return the results and pass those to a `Page` object to use with `PaginationFrontEnd`. The problem is we cannot modify the code to allow `All` as an option when a state is selected. Is there any way to do this?

We can run two separate queries and combine them into one list, but then our pagination is messed up because it doesn't start as a `Page` object and the counts are invalid.

```
public ManualsFrontEnd getAllDocuments(Integer page, Integer total, Documents documentSearchCriteria) {
    if (page == null) page = 0;
    if (total == null) total = 100;
    documentSearchCriteria.setIsActive(1);
    if (documentSearchCriteria.getBrandId() == null) {
        documentSearchCriteria.setBrandId(2);   // Brand = AI
    }

    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, total);
    ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching()
            .withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
            .withIgnoreCase();
    Example<Documents> example = Example.of(documentSearchCriteria, matcher);

    Page<Documents> pageList = documentsRepository.findAll(example, pageable);
    List<Documents> documentList = pageList.getContent();
    List<DocumentsFrontEnd> frontDocList = DocumentMapper.mapViewDocsTOList(documentList);
    PaginationFrontEnd newPagination = new PaginationFrontEnd(toIntExact(pageList.getTotalElements()), pageList.getPageable().getPageNumber() + 1, pageList.getPageable().getPageSize());

    return new ManualsFrontEnd(newPagination, frontDocList);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a custom Specification for the Document class? https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by extending your repository interface from `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

Then you have to create a `Specification` object and implement its

`Predicate toPredicate(Root<Documents> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb)` method to meet your criteria.

Then you can pass this `Specification` object to `repository.findAll` method.